# dd: failed to open ‘kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64.iso’: No such file or directory

Tags: usb, dd, kali

I'm trying to create  a Kali Bootable USB Drive on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS following these instructions -> http://docs.kali.org/downloading/kali-linux-live-usb-install

Everything seemed alright till the last steps, i used:

```
sudo -i
```

to make sure that i was on root priviliges and then:

```
dd if=kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k
```

and get the following:

```
dd: failed to open ‘kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64.iso’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Reviewers: this question is 4 years old and **not** off topic just because it is about 14.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be working from the directory where the .iso file is located. You may have downloaded it as a regular user, but with `sudo -i` you ended up in `/root/`. Use `cd` to get to the directory with the .iso file. If in doubt use `pwd` to see where you are.

EDIT To summarize: suppose the iso file is in the directory Downloads. Then do this:

```
cd Downloads
sudo dd if=kali-linux-1.1.0a-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k
```